# File Browsing window automate

Tags: java, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have total 1500 XML files and i need to pass each of them one by one in a browsing window of a Jar utility and then click the Submit button within that utility.

This creates a Case in a web-application based on that XML values.
Is there any way , i can automate this whole process of uploading the file and clicking on Submit button.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to share how your UI exactly looks like ? is it detectable using selenium?

Comment: @ShekharSwami , Hi no it's not detectable as it's kinda standalone windows application, even if i get the browsing window opened via Auto it, how will i pass files one by one and hit submit Everytime?

Comment: What do you men by 'pass'?

Comment: @Grasshopper Passing as in simply selecting the file one by one in browsing window, sorry for the confusion by word "pass"

Answer (score 0):

1/ rename all your XML files (1.xml - 1500.xml)
2/ create a method to upload one of those files
3/ for num from 1 to 1500 call the upload method